# Are questions about the Historical Method in scope

Tags: discussion

[Why Write another History Book?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8082/why-write-another-history-book) is a question that has been closed. It's not a strong question and that's probably for the best, but I'm not sure people are right to say it's out of scope. A better but similar question would be to ask about the why and how of [historical revisionism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_revisionism). Or perhaps a question about the history of historical revision with respect to a certain subject. These seems like a reasonable questions for this site, but the [faq](https://history.stackexchange.com/faq) doesn't have anything to say here.

So are questions on the [historical method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_method) (not the facts and events but how we study and interpret these facts) in scope?

Comment: By history of historical revision I mean that (with appeasement as an example) the movement from [*Guilty Men*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guilty_Men) to [*Origins of the Second World War*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._J._P._Taylor#The_Origins_of_the_Second_World_War_2) to [*Neville Chamberlain, Appeasement and the British Road to War*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_McDonough#Neville_Chamberlain_and_appeasement) is interesting in it's self and would definitely be looked at in a history course .

Comment: [Do we need a History site...](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/59/do-we-need-a-history-site-what-are-you-getting-out-of-this?rq=1) seems to agree with me.

Comment: Wow.. My question created all this debate :) Is ok if it was closed, sometime it happens. And that question have a great answer anyway...

Comment: And my english is not the best, but if you understand I am happy. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't vote to close it, but only because I wanted the community to have that pleasure.

It wasn't a question about history at all. It was a question about writing, and could only really be properly answered by a writer. That is just so off-topic for History.SE I hardly know where to begin.

As for your other proposed questions, I notice the second word on the Wikipedia link you provided is historiography. We have a [historiography](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historiography) tag, with 7 questions on it. So those are clearly on topic.

Comment: I agree with your decision to close. I apologise for not making that clear. It just made me think about the question why we do continue to write history books. Thanks for pointing out the tag. I see there is one on a particular instance of [functionalism vs intetionalism](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/7412/how-do-functionalists-explain-the-fact-that-holocaust-continued-until-the-very-e). I will say there seem to be a lack of questions on the modern historical method.

Comment: Perhaps we can discuss the matter of history books via Meta or Chat. Even if I voted to close it, the question was interesting, though leading straight to discussion.

Answer (score 5):

It's not so much the question as it is the way it was asked. If you ask "Why write another History book", it invites a list of reason, many or most of which would be subjective in nature. If you ask "What elements go into writing a History book", you might still receive a list, but it will be more finite, AND it can be answered with concrete, objective information. "How would you write another History book" would most likely be viewed in a similar light as the first example, because everybody would have a different opinion, and we are not looking for opinions, but rather facts.

When I review a question, I always think first of the W principles: Who, What, Why, Where, When, and How (which ends in W). ;) Of these, Why and How tend to be the most problematic questions, because they tend to solicit opinions or discussion (debates). It is very important to consider the way a question is worded to ensure that it doesn't fall into that category.

Answer (score 0):

I think that specific questions about historical revisionism as it relates to particular events, and the historical method as it relates to particular events are definitely within scope. As a general rule of thumb the higher away you go from particular events the more likely you are probably writing a question out of scope.